# Selenium - how to select an element with variable text

Tags: java, selenium

```
<div class="order-number">
<h3>"Order number: "<strong>123-123123</strong> </h3>
</div>
```

Any idea how to select the order number? I use Selenium 2. I tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[matches(text(),'\\d+-\\d+']"));
```

But it's not working. Does Xpath2 support regex?

The number of the order is always different, but the style of XXX-XXXXXX is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach would be to search by CSS selector instead:

```
By.cssSelector(".order-number H3 STRONG")
```

It's a bit more frail if the page structure changes though.

A better solution (if you are able to change the page code) is to put an ID on the `<strong>` tag and use `By.id`.  That's much quicker, less frail, and more readable than XPaths or CSS-Selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='order-number']//strong")).getText();
```

Also note that `selenium` supports `matches()` in `XPath`. The cause of your issue seem to be missing closing parenthesis:

*now*

```
matches(text(),'\\d+-\\d+'
```

*should be*

```
matches(text(),'\\d+-\\d+')
```

*working one*

```
//h3/strong[matches(text(),'\d+-\d+')]
```

Comment: Neither way is working for me, always the same result - The string '//h3/strong[matches(text(),'\d+-\d+')]' is not a valid XPath expression.